# How to iterate over an object an replace all nulls to strings

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been trying to run over an object and change every null to string.
First , I wanted to check if I get the values of the object keys.
Thats what I did:

```
 let item = await Item.findOne({itemNumber:'5722'});

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
    console.log(key,value);
  }
```

For some reason the only keys I get their values printed are: isNew, errors , _doc , $init.
and item object has alot more keys.

any tips ?

Comment: Add a sample for item object.

Comment: Please add the schema for the item object.

Comment: `Object.entries()` will only get the "enumerable" own string keys of the object `item`. If `item` has some properties with `enumberable` set to false then they won't appear in the for..of loop

Comment: try `for (const [key, value] of Object.entries({...item})) {` also you should only work with key value pairs you get from `item.toObject()`

Comment: @sabbir.alam my item object's schema is too long (170 fields) so I will not copy it. but I can assure you that I get the right object from my query and if I type "item.itemNumber" I can the right value. it just seems like the for loop stops after the fifth field

Comment: @BarLevin you can try using a method which will get you the enumerable and non-enumerable keys of the object `for(const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(item)) {const value = item[key]; ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert the mongoose document to the plain object using `.toObject` then loop through.

```
 let item = await Item.findOne({itemNumber:'5722'});

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(item.toObject)) {
    console.log(key,value);
  }
```

or

```
 let item = await Item.findOne({itemNumber:'5722'}).lean();
```

Answer (score 0):

use **for/in** loop to iterate over an object properties. e.g.

```
for (p in item) {
 console.log(p + " = " item[p]);
}
```

this will also include anything inherited from its prototype chain that is iterable

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forin.asp